# How can I set Dfile.encoding=utf-8 when building maven project?

Tags: java, maven

`System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());` prints `ISO-8859-1`, so I want to set the defaultCharset to UTF-8.

When tried with `java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar XXX.jar`, I checked that default charset is set to UTF-8.

But is there a way to set `Dfile.encoding=utf-8` option at maven packaging level, so that I can just run `java -jar XXX.jar`?

What I tried:

- `mvn clean package -Dfile.encoding=utf-8`
- pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=utf-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

- `MAVEN_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" mvn clean package`

I prefer controlling with pom.xml file.

Comment: You shouldn't make wrong assumptions about default character encoding in the first line. It's easier to control your own code than to control external environment.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo What do you mean by "control your own code"? Referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding, I thought setting default charset cannot be done by code level. If I'm getting anything wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The answer may depend on your goal - why you want to change it? In tests? Resource filtering? Sources encoding?

Comment: @Lesiak In a log file, a certain language is logged as `???`. I found that it's properly logged when given `Dfile.encoding=utf-8` option, so I want to achieve it without passing Dfile.encoding option everytime I run the app.

Comment: @yoon Do you write this log file in your own code? Then you might just define the `Charset` argument for your `OutputStreamWriter`/`PrintWriter` constructor.

Comment: @yoon you should never use default encoding!

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to pass JVM args for Maven build before runtime.

> Starting with Maven 3.3.1+ you can define JVM configuration via ${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config file which means you can define the options for your build on a per project base. This file will become part of your project and will be checked in along with your project.

So, create .mvn/jvm.config in your project root with content:

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

See the reference: https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-jvm-config-file

Comment: I used `maven surefire plugin` without knowing what it exactly is.. Adding your lines to pom.xml didn't solve the problem. `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());` still prints `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @yoon I see, you need to set up JVM for maven before it start.
I've updated the answer, please try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [define](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable as `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to avoid typing it every time. See the [java command documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-the-jdk_java_options-launcher-environment-variable) for details.

In OpenJDK 18 UTF-8 will be default for all operating systems: [JEP 400](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually I'm finding a way to include that encoding option into a jar or an executable file, so that another person can just run the app without knowing that a certain process(setting env, adding java option, ...) is required.

Comment: In principle there is `System.setProperty` method, you might call it from `main`. But it's a bad practice. This sort of option is supposed to be set from the command line.